# Consuming service reference in web api

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, service-reference

1)I am creating a ASP.NET Web Application-> Empty (Web Api selected) project in VS2013 and adding service reference (wsdl)

```
public class BJKController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public byte[] GetArchive(string workOrderNo)
   {
      BjkClient client =new BjkClient();
      return client.GetInvoice(workorderNo);//I'm getting error this line
   }
}
```

web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICompany" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://service.karakartal.com.tr/Company.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICompany"
          contract="ServiceReference1.ICompany" name="WSHttpBinding_ICompany" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm was debugging and got error in webapi project : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond X.X.XXX.XXX:443

But I am trying a windows project (add service refence too)
everything same (web config and using). It is working fine.

Comment: Can you successfully open the url of your service in your browser?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes. I can debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I moved to IIS it worked fine.